Fill PDF-form with individual data using java
Use case:
Customer's data is collected at the point of sale. Further in the business process, this data needs to be checked and verified and may be augmented with additional data. Therefore, a PDF document with a fillable form is sent to the customer, the already collected data shall be pre-filled in the PDF form, so the customer can make corrections easily, if applicable. Other data will be provided by filling empty fields.
Is there a java framework for filling pdf forms, to pre-fill an empty form with data?

Apache PDFBox lists form filling amongst its features.

Actually any general purpose Java PDF library should do. Consider investigating them and don't forget to take your project requirements into considerations, like acceptable dependency licenses. That being said, strictly speaking library recommendations are off-topic on stackoverflow, you may want to look at [softwarerecs.se].

I will take a closer look into PDFBox. Until now, I've been totally into generating documents using XML FO, but the standard doesn't support forms (I know how to do it with fop images plugin) so my question isn't only about a library but an example how it might be done, however, I'll see how far I can get from here. Thanks for also pointing out the license topic :)
